# How can I activate a model window if it is already open? Solidworks VBA

Tags: vba, solidworks

I am trying to find a way to automatically open the model the drives Drawing View 1. I have the following code which opens the model if it is not open already, but if it is already open, does not activate/show the window with the model open. I would like my code to open the model if it's not already, or switch the window to show the model if it's already open.

```
Dim Part As Object
Dim boolstatus As Boolean
Dim longstatus As Long, longwarnings As Long
Dim swApp As Object
Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2

Sub openpart()

    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    
    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
    
    Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
    boolstatus = Part.ActivateView("Drawing View1")
    boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("Drawing View1", "DRAWINGVIEW", 0, 0, 0, False, 0, Nothing, 0)
    
    If Not swModel Is Nothing Then
    
        Dim swSelMgr As SldWorks.SelectionMgr
        
        Set swSelMgr = swModel.SelectionManager
        
        Dim swView As SldWorks.View
        
        Set swView = swSelMgr.GetSelectedObject6(1, -1)
        
        If Not swView Is Nothing Then
        
            Dim swRefDoc As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
            Set swRefDoc = swView.ReferencedDocument
            
            If swRefDoc Is Nothing Then
                Err.Raise vbError, "", "Drawing view model is not loaded"
            End If
            
            swRefDoc.ShowConfiguration2 swView.ReferencedConfiguration
            
            Dim swConf As SldWorks.Configuration
            Set swConf = swRefDoc.GetConfigurationByName(swView.ReferencedConfiguration)
            
            swConf.ApplyDisplayState swView.DisplayState
            
            swRefDoc.Visible = True
            
            
            
        Else
            Err.Raise vbError, "", "Select drawing view"
        End If
        
    Else
        Err.Raise vbError, "", "No active documents"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To activate an open document, use `ActivateDoc3` Method (`ISldWorks`) as documented [here](https://help.solidworks.com/2017/english/api/sldworksapi/SOLIDWORKS.Interop.sldworks%7ESOLIDWORKS.Interop.sldworks.ISldWorks%7EActivateDoc3.html).

I've changed your code to the following:

```vb
Dim Part As Object
Dim boolstatus As Boolean
Dim longstatus As Long, longwarnings As Long
Dim swApp As Object
Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
Dim swModelAtivated As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
Dim Errors As Long

Sub openpart()
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
    Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
    boolstatus = Part.ActivateView("Drawing View1")
    boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("Drawing View1", "DRAWINGVIEW", 0, 0, 0, False, 0, Nothing, 0)
    
    If Not swModel Is Nothing Then
        Dim swSelMgr As SldWorks.SelectionMgr
        Set swSelMgr = swModel.SelectionManager
        Dim swView As SldWorks.View
        Set swView = swSelMgr.GetSelectedObject6(1, -1)
        Dim docName As String

        If Not swView Is Nothing Then
            Dim swRefDoc As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
            Set swRefDoc = swView.ReferencedDocument

            If swRefDoc Is Nothing Then
                Err.Raise vbError, "", "Drawing view model is not loaded"
            End If

            swRefDoc.ShowConfiguration2 swView.ReferencedConfiguration

            Dim swConf As SldWorks.Configuration
            Set swConf = swRefDoc.GetConfigurationByName(swView.ReferencedConfiguration)
            swConf.ApplyDisplayState swView.DisplayState
            swRefDoc.Visible = True

            docName = swRefDoc.GetTitle

            Set swModelAtivated = swApp.ActivateDoc3(docName, False, swRebuildOnActivation_e.swUserDecision, Errors)
        Else
            Err.Raise vbError, "", "Select drawing view"
        End If
    Else
        Err.Raise vbError, "", "No active documents"
    End If
End Sub
```

I've tested it with a drawing that has only a view named `Drawing View1`. This view refers to a part file. It always activated the file.

Go through the *Remarks* on that link to make sure that you don't have problems when the View refers to a part file that has same name of an assembly file or vice versa.